# Iterate through JSON respone Facebook Graph

Tags: ruby, json, api, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to iterate through a returned response from the Facebook Graph api

```
def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
  puts formatted_data(results)
end

def formatted_data(results)
return unless results
formatted = results['data'].each do |d|
      unless d.nil? 
       {
        message: d['message'],
       }
     end
  formatted.delete_if {|x| x.nil?}
end
end
```

The response is very large so here is a snippet if it helps

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": "197958940234297_827831980580320",
     "from": {
        "category": "Amateur sports team",
        "category_list": [
           {
              "id": "189018581118681",
              "name": "Sports Club"
           },
           {
              "id": "139721016091877",
              "name": "Outdoor Recreation"
           },
           {
              "id": "109615542448700",
              "name": "Physical Fitness"
           }
        ],
        "name": "Varsity Vandals",
        "id": "197958940234297"
     },
     "to": {
        "data": [
           {
              "id": "668983363",
              "name": "Heather Walker"
           },
           {
              "id": "638195502",
              "name": "Emma Williams"
           },
           {
              "id": "1286337937",
              "name": "Becky Williams"
           }
        ]
     },
     "with_tags": {
        "data": [
           {
              "id": "668983363",
              "name": "Heather Walker"
           },
           {
              "id": "638195502",
              "name": "Emma Williams"
           },
           {
              "id": "1286337937",
              "name": "Becky Williams"
           }
        ]
     },
     "message": "Great turnout for the women's intro session today. Cool to have a women's game and a men's game running side by side. Touch is for all.",
     "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-0/1507550_827829843913867_410211203232735862_s.jpg",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=827829843913867&set=pcb.827831980580320&type=1&relevant_count=2",
     "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "https://www.facebook.com/197958940234297/posts/827831980580320"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "https://www.facebook.com/197958940234297/posts/827831980580320"
        }
     ],
     "privacy": {
        "value": ""
     },
```

I am getting an error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

At the moment i would just like to pull out all the Messages from the JSON object...Am i handling the extraction correctly

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: In which line you are getting this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure your not using the data key twice?

`results = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']` in main method and `formatted = results['data'].each` in your formatted_data method?

Thinking maybe?

```
def def formatted_data(results)
  return unless results
  results['data'].map {|m| {message: m['message']} }.compact
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried you code, I change you require is move `formatted.delete_if {|x| x.nil?}` out of loop, like following, as `formatted` will be `nil` inside the loop.

```
    def formatted_data(results)
      return unless results
      formatted = results['data'].each do |d|
          unless d.nil? 
           {
            message: d['message'],
           }
         end

       end
    formatted.delete_if {|x| x.nil?}
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)

  messages = format_data(response)
  for message in messages do
      puts message
  end
end

def format_data(response, new_data = [])
    if response.present?
        results = JSON.parse(response)
        for result in results do
           new_data << result[:data][:message]  if result[:data][:message].present?
        end
        return new_data #-> array of messages
    end
end
```